# Implementing Find Previous functionality of Webview in Android

Tags: android, search, webview

I made an Xamarin Android Application that loads a webpage in webview. I used webview.FindAll and webview.FindNext in it. Does anyone know how to implement Find Previous in webview. Here are my codes:

```
   using Android.App;
   using Android.Widget;
   using Android.OS;
   using Android.Views;
   using System;
    using Java.Lang.Reflect;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace App1
   {
          [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    WebView WebView;
    private LinearLayout container;
    private Button nextButton, SearchButton;
    private EditText findBox;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        WebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        nextButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNext);
        SearchButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnPrev);
        findBox = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Search);
        findBox.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        findBox.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        WebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        WebView.LoadUrl("http://athena.fhict.nl/users/i298536/Index.html");
        Search();

}


    private void Search()
    {

        nextButton.Click += delegate

         { WebView.FindNext(true);


         };





        SearchButton.Click += delegate

        {
           WebView.FindAll(findBox.Text.ToString());




            try
            {

                Method m = WebView.Class.GetMethod("setFindIsUp", Java.Lang.Boolean.Type);
                m.Invoke(WebView, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) { }

        };







    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

```
    WebView.FindNext(false);
```

it works to go back to the previously found word.
 while

```
        WebView.FindNext(true);
```

is to go the next found word.

I posted this for those who are still looking for the answer