# Search string inside WebView in Kotlin/Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm a newbie in Android and Kotlin. I'm  developing an app that gets HTML files from a site and show it in a WebView. I need to build a functionality as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> (Find Command) in `WebNavigators` that find a string searched and scrolls the screen until the match string found. And a button to the next and previous matches.

I'm trying the following code but it's not working:

```
myWebView.findAllAsync("Test in HTML file") 
myWebView.findNext(true)
```

Could anyone help me or give me a direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after search and search, I found the answer. Posting here because may be useful for anyone more.
Based on [this article](https://www.programering.com/a/MDM0ADMwATY.html) and [this ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620665/implementing-find-previous-functionality-of-webview-in-android), I did build my code :

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     /// *... blah blah my code no related to this issue*
    wv_contentArticle.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/articles/w.html") // loading file - just a test
    sv_contentPage.isSubmitButtonEnabled
    // bellow listen the searchview 

    sv_contentPage.setOnQueryTextListener(object :    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String): Boolean {
            return true
        }
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {

            if (!query.isEmpty()) {
                    sv_contentPage.clearFocus()  // to hide keyboard 
                    wv_contentArticle.findAllAsync(query) // look for string
                    try {
                        val m = WebView::class.java.getMethod("setFindIsUp", 
java.lang.Boolean.TYPE) // THIS WAS MISSING, WITHOUT IT THIS WILL NOT WORK
                        m.invoke(wv_contentArticle, true) // THIS WAS MISSING, WITHOUT IT THIS WILL NOT WORK

                    } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
                    }
            }
        return true
        }
    })
    bt_findNext.setOnClickListener {  wv_contentArticle.findNext(true)  } // find next one
    bt_findPrevious.setOnClickListener {  wv_contentArticle.findNext(false) } // find previous one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Kotlin function is quite standard for searching:

```
operator fun CharSequence.contains(
    char: Char, 
    ignoreCase: Boolean = false
): Boolean (source)
```

In WebView `.contains()` method is more useful inside `if-statement`:

```
import android.webkit.WebView

val str: String = // blah-blah-blah ;

if (str.contains("Test in HTML file", false))
    return true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, very useful but is not what exactly I need for.